Denial of boarding or ticketing issue - best path forward
In June 2023, my family and I were supposed to fly to Paris (from JFK). The flight was booked through our bank (paid with points and cash - the bank is therefore the travel agent), the marketing airline was Delta and operating airline Air France.
When we showed up at the airport 4 hours before the flight, Air France informed us that they couldn't find our tickets, as they were canceled by "revenue management". They had signs on the counters asking for volonteers to take later flights. At the airport, we also spoke to Delta (marketing airline), who said they could see our confirmed tickets and gave me a hand written note saying we were denied boarding. I asked for compensation and lodging and this was not possible according to the agent. We called our bank and they worked with Delta to put us on a Virgin Atlantic flight two days later.
Since then, I have taken the following actions:

Raised a denial of boarding complaint with Delta to get the DOT compensation. They denied it and pointed fingers at Air France and the bank who booked our tickets.
Raised a complaint with Air France, who pointed fingers at the bank (they think it is a ticketing issue).
Raised a complaint with our bank, who pointed fingers at Delta and Air France. They did confirm that we were correctly ticketed and provided an email with ticket #.
Tried other Avenues (including BBB, ADR and small claim lawsuit) that are still in progress. The airlines and their lawyers have been very successful at dragging the process.

I know that you will all say that's the perfect example confirming that booking directly with the airline is strongly recommended. I get that and agree, I learned my lesson.
My question is: what's my best course of action to either get the DOT denial of boarding compensation or EU261 compensation? How do I confirm if it is a true case of denial of boarding or as Air France says, a ticketing issue? Should I continue the ADR path and small claim processes?
I have gathered strong evidence (email from the bank confirming that we were ticketed, 2 notes from Delta confirming denial of boarding, Delta audit coupon etc), but holding the three parties accountable (bank, Air France and Delta) has been extremely challenging. They all point fingers at each other and give different versions (Delta and the bank agree it is a denial of boarding case, Air France says it is a ticketing issue likely caused by the bank).

In terms of EU261, the case is pretty clear: You were involuntarily denied boarding with a valid ticket and Air France is responsible as they are the operating carrier. The statute of limitations is 5 years in France (although the airline may state less in their terms and conditions), so you are still inside the valid time window.
File an EU 261 claim against Air France and elevate to their local aviation authority if they deny it. Alternatively, you can farm out the claim to a third party EU261 collector, which will handle the denial and possibly go to court if needed. Of course, they will charge you for that.

Most of them charge (a percentage of the compensation received, varies between 30% and 50% AFAIK) only if they are successful.

Unfortunately the French national enforcement body does NOT adjudicate in individual cases. There's a mediation service at https://www.mtv.travel but in my experience they're utterly useless. Court is likely the best bet

This is certainly correct, but if you think about it it's kind of wild that OP as the customer has to argue with anybody aside from the party that originally sold them the ticket. It feels kind of weird for a commercial reseller to be able to take your money and then go "hey, I gave you some sort of ticket number, what happened afterwards is none of my business."

@xLeitix The fact is the liability does NOT rest with "the party that originally sold them the ticket", but rather the operating carrier. It's them you claim from, and it's them you sue if they refuse

@xLeitix: a) you have no idea what happened here and its quite possible that Air France bungled the ticket (which they have done for me before). b) EU 261 fortunately is clear about the operating carrier being responsible. That's a really good choice since otherwise the passenger  & courts would have to deal with 1000s of individual  retailers. The operating carrier is always free to recoup damages from their business partners

Thanks all for the inputs. In court (US/NY small claim), Air France has argued that this was a ticketing issue caused by the bank (and not a case of denial of boarding) and provided the log showing that the flight was not overbooked. They haven't proved out that there was a ticketing issue though. As a consequence, Air France, Delta and the bank are all part of the lawsuit. So it is taking forever. Maybe I should do the EU 261 case with Air France only, but they will say it is a ticketing issue again, and the compensation would be lower (2,400 euros for 4 passengers vs. 400% ticket in the US).

@Catzman55 Oh wow, didn't know US regulations entitled you to 400% of the ticket price! Focus on the ongoing case you have then, and if you haven't already, submit the proof that you had a confirmed ticket ASAP

As Hilmar said, Air France is the legally liable party, so any court claim needs to be made against Air France and ONLY Air France. Present ALL the evidence you have and refer to section 7 of the preamble to Regulation EC261/2004 stating it's the operating carrier that's legally responsible.

(+1) The different sections in the preamble are usually called “recitals”. They are not really binding but all the important articles also explicitly refer to the “operating carrier” and this term is defined in article 2(b).

Thank you both for your response. I am just worried that Air France will again say that it is a ticketing issue, but I will try that route too

@Catzman55 Doesn't matter, you have proof that you had a confirmed ticket, so just make sure to use it in your evidence
